# Push object away from another object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vector, 2d

I'm trying to call a method 20 times per second to push point A away from point B.
The method should use the following variables:

- Point A (X)
- Point A (Y)
- Point B (X)
- Point B (Y)
- Strength

The closer point A and B are together the faster they will move away from each other.
The strength variable controls the distance per tick and the distance between the points where point A won't be pushed anymore...

Basically I'm trying to slowly push the cursor away from a specified point.

Any ideas how I could implement this?

[image: sketch]

This is my attempt, unfortunately the cursor moves faster if the distance increases...

```
    'PosX and PosY are the percentage of the screen width/height

    'Calculate the real position
    Dim ScreenPosX As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width * (PosX / 100)
    Dim ScreenPosY As Integer = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height * (PosY / 100)

    Dim PointOffsetX As Integer = Cursor.Position.X - ScreenPosX
    Dim PointOffsetY As Integer = Cursor.Position.Y - ScreenPosY

    If PointOffsetX > -Strength And PointOffsetX < Strength Then
        Dim StrengthFactorX As Integer = Strength - ScreenOffsetX
        Dim StrengthFactorY As Integer = Strength - ScreenOffsetY

        Cursor.Position = New Point(Cursor.Position.X + StrengthFactorX, Cursor.Position.Y + StrengthFactorY)
        'Would be the same for Y. Obviously doesn't work though.
    End If
```

Comment: **What have you tried?** StackOverflow typically won't respond well to questions like this, essentially a "code it for me". All you have is a problem statement and a question -- there's no evidence of any effort at all from your side. Try something first, come back with a more specific question showing your code & your specific issue.

Comment: too wide question. What drawing technology you use ? GDI ? Some 2D library ? Windows forms ? WPF ?

Comment: @Tigran I think drawing is irrelevant to the question.. its just an illustration.

Comment: Yes, I just need to calculate the points. Sorry for not adding my code, I didn't think there was a point in adding it...
I'll add it in a few seconds.

Comment: You could easily and exactly solve for the displacement with a *projectile motion* formula, incrementing your time exponentially on each iteration of your calculation.

Comment: If you are 'push(ing) point A away from point B' can the distance decrease?  Should we assume that the drawing / calculations are in some timed mechanism?

Comment: The method to push the point away will be called **20 times per second**

Comment: You need to find the normal vector, then it's easy to get the point you want.

Comment: Is the problem the speed, the drawing, or both?

Comment: The speed and the fact that the object should become slower when the distance increases, not faster.

Comment: You should consider implementing a vector-based solution (just as @the_lotus mentioned) so that you can calculate the strength (force) and direction (normal) that needs to be applied.

[This sample](http://software.xfx.net/stackoverflow/KeepAway.zip) utilizes a Vector class to calculate both the force and direction in which PointB should be "pushed away" from the center of PointA as the cursor approaches PointA.

But, applying the required changes (offsets) to the cursor position might be a challenge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me. I used a button and the timer ontick event. You can adjust the constants.

```
Dim currentObjectAccelerationX As Decimal = 0
Dim currentObjectAccelerationY As Decimal = 0

Dim currentObjectPointX As Decimal
Dim currentObjectPointY As Decimal

Const maxDistance As Integer = 50
Const accelerationDenominator As Integer = 50
Const deceleration As Decimal = 0.2

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    currentObjectPointX = Button1.Location.X
    currentObjectPointY = Button1.Location.Y

    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub onTick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim MousePointX As Integer = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X
    Dim MousePointY As Integer = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y

    Dim OffsetX As Decimal = currentObjectPointX - MousePointX
    Dim OffsetY As Decimal = currentObjectPointY - MousePointY



    If Math.Abs(OffsetX) < maxDistance AndAlso Math.Abs(OffsetY) < maxDistance Then


        Dim accelerationX As Decimal = 0
        Dim accelerationY As Decimal = 0

        If OffsetX > 0 Then
            accelerationX = 1 + (maxDistance - OffsetX) / accelerationDenominator
        Else
            accelerationX = -1 + (-maxDistance - OffsetX) / accelerationDenominator
        End If

        If OffsetY > 0 Then
            accelerationY = 1 + (maxDistance - OffsetY) / accelerationDenominator
        Else
            accelerationY = -1 + (-maxDistance - OffsetY) / accelerationDenominator
        End If


        currentObjectAccelerationX += accelerationX
        currentObjectAccelerationY += accelerationY
    End If

    currentObjectPointX += currentObjectAccelerationX
    currentObjectPointY += currentObjectAccelerationY

    If (Math.Abs(currentObjectAccelerationX) <= deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationX = 0
    ElseIf (currentObjectAccelerationX > deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationX -= deceleration
    ElseIf (currentObjectAccelerationX < deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationX += deceleration
    End If

    If (Math.Abs(currentObjectAccelerationY) <= deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationY = 0
    ElseIf (currentObjectAccelerationY > deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationY -= deceleration
    ElseIf (currentObjectAccelerationY < deceleration) Then
        currentObjectAccelerationY += deceleration
    End If

    Button1.Location = New Point(currentObjectPointX, currentObjectPointY)
End Sub
```